# Can't run java file (having trouble with classpath fixes)

Tags: java, package, classpath

I'm remoted into a Linux machine that I don't own from my Windows machine. I've got 2 java files:

```
DBConnect.java
Main.java
```

I compile and run them fine on my machine and in my IDE (I'm using NetBeans). When I copy them to the remote Linux machine, the place they're located is:

```
/home/NETID/myname/430
```

I compile them using:

```
javac *.java
```

They compile successfully, which creates two new files:

```
DBConnect.class
Main.class
```

I then attempt to run Main.class. With each of the following commands, I get the error "Error: Could not find or load main class Main"

```
java Main
java <pkg>.Main
java <pkg>/Main
```

In my case, in NetBeans, my project is called MyProject. In the directory structure on the left-hand side of the IDE window, there is MyProject. Under that is a file called Source Packages. In that file is another thing called pkgMyProject. When I expand that, I see my two java files.

Also, at the top of both Main.java and DBConnect.java, there is:

```
package pkgMyProject;
```

I've read some other questions here referring to this issue, but I'm having trouble understanding the answers. Also, many of the answers don't apply because I don't think I can set the classpath on the remote machine.

When I check my classpath in my terminal (when I'm remotely connected) using...

```
echo ${CLASSPATH}
```

...nothing is displayed.

How can I find my classpath, and how can I run these files?

Comment: `I don't think I can set the classpath on the remote machine.` No, you can do something like `java -cp . Main`

Comment: Also you can set `CLASSPATH` using `export CLASSPATH=/path/to/somewhere` if you are using bash

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the package folder. You need to create a directory in the Linux machine with the name `pkgMyProject`. Then, run `javac pkgMyProject/*.java` and run `java -cp . pkgMyProject.Main` after that.

Update: You can add the `-cp` to set the classpath to be used in the java command.

Comment: You might want to include the information given in the comments about setting up the classpath, too.

Comment: Perfect, that worked. Few questions for you!  1)  What's the purpose of having a directory of the package name in which all of those files are stored? Is it just like "here's a package of files, and they're all packaged up within this directory"?  2)  What does the "." do when I'm running Main? Does it just mean "this directory"?  3)  If it does, then I'm saying "run a java program, from this directory, but the path to the class file is to first go into pkgMyProject and it'll be there."  Correct?

Comment: 1- it is a language specific requirement. In an enterprise project you will have a lot more than 2 classes. The folder/package structure allows you to separate your system in modules or layers according to your architecture. Also, usually you will package the compiled files in a `.jar` file to deploy them.   2- Yes it means “this directory” 3- Yes, the full class name in java consist of the package plus the class name in the file. It is called the fully qualified name.